# Link to Open Tabs

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

i want to edit this code to make links from inside tab open another tab

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.bhoechie-tab-menu>div.list-group>a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings('a.active').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        var index = $(this).index();
        $("div.bhoechie-tab>div.bhoechie-tab-content").removeClass("active");
        $("div.bhoechie-tab>div.bhoechie-tab-content").eq(index).addClass("active");
        
        
    });
    
});
```

Comment: The `java` tag is not correct

Comment: can you edit the code for me ? @Mark